# Undefined method `answer' for class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have form where I can ask question and add to that question few answers.
When I try to save my question and answers clicking 'create' I get error:

```
"undefined method `answer'" in questions_controller.rb in 'create' method.
```

My question.rb model:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

  before_save { self.content = content.downcase }
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 150 }
end
```

My answer.rb model:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question

  validates :answer, presence: true, length: { maximum: 150 }
end
```

questions_controller.rb:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @question = Question.new
    3.times do
      answer = @question.answers.build
    end
  end

  def create
    @question = Question.new(question_params)
    if @question.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @question
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def question_params
      params.require(:question).permit(:content, answers_attributes: [:content])
    end
end
```

and view new.html.erb:

```
<div class="row center-block">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for @question do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

        <%= f.label :content %>
        <%= f.text_field :content %>

        <%= f.fields_for :answers do |builder| %>
            <%= render "answer_fields", :f => builder %>
        <% end %>

        <div class="center hero-unit">
            <%= f.submit "Create Poll", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

and rendered answer_fields:

```
<p>
  <%= f.label :content %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :content, :rows => 3 %><br>
  <%= f.check_box :_destroy %>
  <%= f.label :_destroy, "Remove answer"%>
</p>
```

Comment: You should whitelist question_id as well ,  params.require(:question).permit(:content, answers_attributes: [question_id, :content])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to track the problem without the stack trace, but what made me suspicious is in your form, you have field `content` for `Answer`:

```
<%= f.text_area :content, :rows => 3 %>
```

this is properly processed in your controller by (again - you're allowing `:content` for `answers_attributes`)

```
params.require(:question).permit(:content, answers_attributes: [:content])
```

But you have validation in `Answer` on field `:answer`:

```
validates :answer, presence: true, length: { maximum: 150 }
```

Try changing that to

```
validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 150 }
```

Hope that helps!